# Is there a way to lock a bone axis? rigging

Tags: rigging

i wan't to make some of my bones like the elbow to just move in one axis for better animation, is there a way? I'm searching but i can't find an answer

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, while in pose mode you will find a Transform Locks panel in the bone properties, these are also available in the 3D viewports properties region <kbd>N</kbd>. This can prevent a user transforming specific axes.

[image: transform locks]

A more rigid approach is to use constraints, There are several [limit transform constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/index.html#transform) that will prevent bones being moved or rotated outside of your settings. Here you can also set limits, so you can allow a bone to rotate 30 degrees on one axis.

The transform locks only apply to the viewport, an fcurve or driver can move a bone with these locks enabled. Constraints are applied after fcurves so can prevent an extrapolated fcurve from going outside your settings.

**Update for 2.8x**

From 2.80 the transform locks have been moved into the same panel as the transform values. They also don't visually stand out as buttons.

[image]

Comment: ....in blender 2.8...

Comment: @tatsu it is a small change, in the properties editor, they are now with the location values. While the padlocks don't look like they are on raised buttons, they work the same.

Comment: This answer locks the bone relative to its parent bone, which can still move it around. If you want to lock the bone to a specific place in the world, you need to [add IK to it](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/introduction.html).